# get_content_file from a JSON file

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I need to get the content of a json file.

I use:

```
$message_path = 'path/to/message.json';
$data = file_get_contents("$message_path");

echo $data;
```

Here is the message.json:

```
{
  "message": "hello ${last_name} ${first_name}\nblabla",
  "date": null,
  "state": "DRAFT",
  "externalUrl": null,
  "landingPageType": "custom",
  "landingPageTitle": null,
  "sourceAddress": null,
  "flash": false,
  "type": 'STANDARD',
  "scheduledType": "now"
}
```

and here, the echo:

```
"{n  "message": "hello ${last_name} ${first_name}nblabla",n  "date": null,n  "state": "DRAFT",n  "externalUrl": null,n  "landingPageType": "custom",n  "landingPageTitle": null,n  "sourceAddress": null,n  "flash": false,n  "type": 'STANDARD',n  "scheduledType": "now"n}
```

Why all these 'n' characters ? How to remove this ?

Answer (score 0):

These `n`s are linebreaks. Just [parse `$data` to JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and eveything should be OK.